# Component attribute value cut off

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-template

I have the following component `(app-stone)` which has an `id` attribute, a child component is using the `@Input()` function to receive the `id` attribute from the parent. Can anyone tell me why the value on the parent is different from the value on the child, if you look at `ng-reflect-id` and the `id=`

```
<app-stone ng-reflect-id="878b591d-8adc-4156-a5ae-a3df8b">
    <div class="stone active" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" id="878b591d-8adc-4156-a5ae-a3df8ba721bc">
    </div>
</app-stone>
```

many thanks

Comment: by the way I have edited the html for brevity's sake

Comment: show the class and html

Comment: no concatenation, thats why I am confused - trying to work out why there would be a difference